# How to detect if a thread is active

Tags: windows, visual-c++, boost-thread

Using MS VC++ and Boost thread, I have a routine -in fact a Windows procedure- in the main thread, that is called many times. In each call, the routine creates a new thread - I'm planning create the thread object into persistent space via **new** and attach the result to an global -static- pointer-.  The condition es that I need terminate the previous one if in the next call to the reoutine, the previous thread is still running.

I've read: "Just as the lifetime of a file may be different from the lifetime of an iostream object which represents the file, the lifetime of a thread of execution may be different from the  thread object which represents the thread of execution. In particular, after a call to join(), the thread of execution will no longer exist even though the thread object continues to exist until the end of its normal lifetime. The converse is also possible; if a thread object is destroyed without join() having first been called, the thread of execution continues until its initial function completes".

Before reinvent the wheel the question: Is there a standard method to detect if the thread is still running?  In such case: what is the canonical method to terminate it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to end a thread is through `join` or `interrupt`, depending on what exactly your thread does.
As far as I know there is no single function that returns whether the thread is still running or not, however you can try calling `timed_join` with a 0 wait time:

> Returns:
>
> true if *this refers to a thread of execution on entry, and that thread of execution has completed before the call times out, false
>   otherwise.

Comment: although pending to check that, the `timed_join` method should be sufficient. In respecto to `join`, as far as I know, simply holds the main thread until the new end, so I must use `interrupt` -I suppose-

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `joinable` method?

> Returns true if *this refers to a thread of execution, false otherwise.

There are two ways to terminate the thread: `join` which is somewhat cleaner, or you can call `detach`.

Comment: I think there are a common misunderstand about the semantic of `join`. If I understand correctly, `join` actually not termenate the thread, but holds the main thread until the new one terminates by its own. In respect to to `joinable`surely will server for the mentioned propose. In respecto to `detach`I must admit that have not a clear idea about what means "the thread of execution becomes detached".

Comment: That is correct, you join the thread if you want to block until the thread of execution is finished. Typically you would be waiting for some sort of result, etc. However in cases where you are not concerned with the state of the thread anymore, you can call detach, which allows it to carry on running until it's natural end i.e. it should just carry on doing what it is doing until it is finished, but you are not waiting for any result i.e. your program can carry on without knowing about what the thread is doing.

Comment: Thanks for your crisp explanation about the `detach` option.